# how can i input string with more than two words in a single input?

Tags: java, input

i want to input a String like
america
south korea
japan

and want to store it in array. I am able to do it for countries having one word name but for text having more than one word eg how can i add south korea nextLine() is not working i did this.

```
String c=new String[2];
for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
{
c=sc.next();  //taking one word
//tried sc.nextLine() also;
}
```

Comment: "`nextLine()` is not working" how is it not working? Because that's exactly what I would expect to use.

Comment: Inputting from the command line, I'm assuming?

Comment: Scanner.nextLine() returns the rest of the line as a String. How is that not working?

Comment: See here for potential reason why `nextLine()` wasn't working for you: [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13102045/5221149)

Comment: i hope you din't try `nextLine` on string array

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
String c= null;

c=sc.nextLine();
String[] split = c.split(" ");
for(String x : split)
System.out.println(x);
```

Output :

```
america south korea japan
america
south
korea
japan
```

You are assigning an string array to string variable.

String c = new String[2]; is wrong initialization

String[] c = new String[2]; is proper initialization

If you want to try with array Try this code :

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String[] c= new String[3];
for(int i=0;i<3;i++) {
     c[i]=sc.nextLine();
}
for(String x : c)
    System.out.println(x);
}
```

Output :

```
america
South Korea
Japan
america
South Korea
Japan
```